# Remove Search box in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Running Windows 10 Pro (OS Build 19041.572). In File Explorer, there is an odd "Search" field that appears on the same level as the path (see image).

[image: Search field in File Explorer]

Can this be removed? This functionality is not required. If I need to search a folder, I'll do it in a different way (such as `dir *.xml /s` from a command prompt).

Comment: Something I discovered today is that you can drag the Search box and make it smaller by putting the mouse pointer in that gap between the Navigation and Search boxes.

Comment: * make it smaller * awesome! windows search is awful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That box cannot be removed. It is built into Windows Explorer which is built into Windows. This is true for your version, the newer production version available and Windows Insider as well.

This request (and modifications of the Windows Explorer ribbon) have come up before. These are all fixed in place (I think to allow Explorer to work as a subsystem to other apps).

Comment: Thanks John. That's a disappointing design choice.

Comment: This answer is outdated, and it *is* possible to remove the search box. See @jensrobot's answer below.
The [Hide Explorer Search Bar](https://github.com/valinet/HideExplorerSearchBar) program is super lightweight and does exactly what it says.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the top google result when searching for this i wanna add that this is now possible with a 3rd party open source tool called [ExplorerPatcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher).

After download and install, just right click taskbar -> `Properties` -> `File Explorer` and there should be a setting for `Hide search bar completely`

Comment: Thanks! This led me to another program from the same dev called Hide Explorer Search Bar. It's a tiny executable that does exactly that.
https://github.com/valinet/HideExplorerSearchBar

Answer (score 0):

For now, only way seems to be: remove entire address panel. Then you can set title to show you full path, and it will be kind of like non-interactive address bar. You can do this via custom Windows Theme or via DLL-injecting programs like OldNewExplorer and others. You can also remove ribbon and control panel too, making not that bad, minimalistic style for Explorer like this:

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that using (great) DLL-injector tools like OldNewExplorer, risks getting you banned on videogame services.

Answer (score -1):

**Regedit.exe**

```
Click Start, type Regedit.exe and press ENTER
Navigate to the following branch:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer

The above key may not exist by default, and you may need to create the above branch manually.
Create a DWORD value named DisableSearchBoxSuggestions
Double-click DisableSearchBoxSuggestions and set its data as 1
Exit the Registry Editor.
```

**Cmd**

```
 Click Start, type Cmd and press ENTER

reg add HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer /v DisableSearchBoxSuggestions /t reg_dword /d 1
```

Comment: Did not work on my PC, even after a reboot (search box is still there in File Explorer).

Comment: The registry key in question doesn’t disable the search functionality entirely, specifically hide it, making it inaccessible.  It simply disabled suggestions when text is typed in the field.

Answer (score -1):

Try to modify the following registry key to see if it was helpful.

**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer**

Value Name  **NoShellSearchButton**

Value Type  **REG_DWORD**

Enabled Value   **1**

Disabled Value  **0**

Please reboot your PC after modifying above key.

If it was not helpful, here is a similar thread discussed before, you could have a look:

[File explorer search removal or disable](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/file-explorer-search-removal-or-disable.3010499/)

Comment: That did not remove the search bar and the linked thread did not help. According to this article, this only applies to earlier versions of Windows: https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsExplorer::NoShellSearchButton